# If $V,W$ are Banach spaces, $\Omega\subseteq V$ is open, $f:\Omega\to W$ is differentiable and ${\rm D}f$ is bounded, then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let

- $V,W$ be $\mathbb R$-Banach spaces
- $\Omega\subseteq V$ be open
- $f:\Omega\to W$

It's easy to see that if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0\in\Omega$, then there is some $\delta>0$ with $$\left\|f(x)-f(x_0)\right\|_W\le(1+\left\|{\rm D}f(x_0)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(V,\:W)})\left\|x-x_0\right\|_V\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in B_\delta(x_0)\tag 1$$ where $B_\delta(x_0)$ is the open ball in $\Omega$ around $x_0$ with radius $\delta$, i.e. $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous at $x_0$.

> Now suppose that $f$ is differentiable (at each point) and ${\rm D}f$ is bounded. I would like to show that $f$ must be Lipschitz continuous, i.e. there is some $C\ge 0$ with $$\left\|f(x_1)-f(x_2)\right\|_W\le C\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|_V\;\;\;\text{for all }x_1,x_2\in\Omega.\tag 2$$

Let $x_1,x_2\in\Omega$. Since ${\rm D}f$ is bounded, there is some $\tilde C\ge 0$ with $$\left\|{\rm D}f(x_0)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(V,\:W)}\le\tilde C\;\;\;\text{for all }x_0\in V\tag 3$$ and hence we obtain the existence of $\delta_i>0$ with $$\left\|f(x)-f(x_i)\right\|_W\le(1+\tilde C)\left\|x-x_i\right\|_V\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in B_{\delta_i}(x_i)\tag 4$$ from $(1)$ for $i=1,2$.

> However, in the case $B_{\delta_1}(x_1)\cap B_{\delta_2}(x_2)=\emptyset$ we cannot immediately conclude $(2)$ from $(4)$. So, the question is: *How can we prove $(2)$*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is called the mean value theorem (for differentiable functions in a Banach space). One version of the statement is that if $f$ is differentiable on a convex open set $U$, and $\|Df\|\leq M$ then 
$$ \forall x,y\in U : \|f(x) - f(y)\| \leq M \|x-y\|$$

A typical proof goes as follows: Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider the set $E$ of values $t\in [0,1]$ for which $$\forall \ 0\leq s\leq t \ \ \Rightarrow
 \ \|f(y+s(x-y))-f(y)\| \leq \epsilon+ s(M+\epsilon)  \|x-y\|$$
Then $0\in E$ so $a=\sup E$ exists. The above inequality holds for $s=a$ by continuity of $f$. Suppose that $a<1$ then there is a squence $s_n\rightarrow a^+$ for which the inequality fails. Taking limits we must have:
$$
  \|f(y+a(x-y))-f(y)\| = \epsilon+ a(M+\epsilon)  \|x-y\|$$
As $f$ is differentiable at $u=y+a(x-y)$ there is $\delta>0$ so that
  $$ \|f(u+s(x-y))-f(u)\| \leq (M+\epsilon)s $$
whenever $0\leq s\leq \delta$. Adding this to the previous we see by the triangular inequality that $a+\delta\in E$, contrary to the definition of $a$. Therefore, $a=1\in E$. Now, letting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$  one obtains the claim.

Comment: Is there a proof which uses the result $(1)$? By the way, your statement doesn't yield $(2)$, cause $\Omega$ in the question isn't convex. Doesn't the statement hold for non-convex open sets?

Comment: The statement is in fact wrong for non convex set (I should have mentioned this before). It is easy to make counter examples. If you look at my proof it  uses in fact your result (1) except that one replaces the term 1 by an epsilon to get an optimal bound in the end.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample in mind?

Comment: Take a cut annulus in the $(x,y)$ plane which  in polar coordinates is: $\{(r,\phi): 1< r <3, 0<\phi<2\pi\}$. Think of $r,\phi$ as functions of $x,y$. The function $f(x,y)=\phi(x,y)$ is differentiable with a uniformly bounded derivative, but $f(2,-\epsilon)-f(2,\epsilon) \rightarrow 2\pi$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$.

Comment: What about the converse statement? If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, then $$\frac{\left\|f(x)-f(x_0)\right\|_W}{\left\|x-x_0\right\|_V}\le C\;\;\;\text{for all }x,x_0\in\Omega\text{ with }x\ne x_0\tag 5$$ for some $C\ge 0$. In light of [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) we cannot expect that $(5)$ yields the differentiability of $f$, so let's assume that $f$ is differentiable too. The question is: Can we show that ${\rm D}f$ is bounded? Fix $x_0\in\Omega$.

Comment: By $(5)$ we obtain $$\frac{\left\|{\rm D}f(x_0)(x-x_0)\right\|_W}{\left\|x-x_0\right\|_V}\le\frac{\left\|f(x)-f(x_0)-{\rm D}f(x_0)(x-x_0)\right\|_W}{\left\|x-x_0\right\|_V}+C\:\stackrel{\left\|x-x_0\right\|_V\to 0}\to\:C\tag 6$$ for all $x\in\Omega\setminus\left\{x_0\right\}$. However, this doesn't yield immediately that $$x_0\mapsto\left\|{\rm D}f(x_0)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(V,\:W)}=\sup_{x\in\Omega\setminus\left\{x_0\right\}}\frac{\left\|{\rm D}f(x_0)(x-x_0)\right\|_W}{\left\|x-x_0\right\|_V}\tag 7$$ is bounded, does it?

Comment: @0xbadf00d  The converse is indeed true. If $f$ is C-Lipschitz and differentiable at $x_0$ then $\|Df(x_0)\|\leq L$. This is because $Df$ is linear so an estimate in a $\delta>0$ neighborhood extends to the whole vector space: Given $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta$ so that when $|v|<\delta$ then $|Df(x_0)v|\leq (C+\epsilon) |v|$. Now use linearity to show that this holds for every $v$.

Comment: ${\rm D}f$ is **not** linear, but ${\rm D}f(x_0)$ is. I guess you've meant that.

Comment: Unfortunately not: (a) Let's be precise: You're talking about *local* properties of $f$, i.e. you assume that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous at $x_0$ with Lipschitz constant $C$ and differentiable at $x_0$. You state that then $\left\|{\rm D}f(x_0)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(V,\:W)}\le C$. Let $ε>0$. It's clear that the Lipschitz and differentiability properties together imply the existence of some $δ>0$ with $$\frac{\left\|{\rm D}f(x_0)(x-x_0)\right\|_W}{\left\|x-x_0\right\|_V}\le ε+C\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in Ω\setminus\left\{x_0\right\}\text{ with }\left\|x-x_0\right\|_V<δ\;.\tag 8$$

Comment: However, I don't get how I can extend this inequality to all $x\in\Omega\setminus\left\{x_0\right\}$. (b) I'm confused about the assumptions: As stated in $(1)$, if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ it is *automatically* Lipschitz continuous at $x_0$ (so, we don't need to additionally assume that) with Lipschitz constant $\tilde\varepsilon+\left\|{\rm D}f(x_0)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(V,\:W)}$ for any $\tilde\varepsilon>0$. And what really confuses me is that this means that if $f$ is differentiable at each point, ${\rm D}f$ must be bounded. Is that really true?

Comment: Suppose $|Df(x_0)v|\leq (C+\epsilon) |v|$ for $|v|<\delta$. Let $w$ be any vector. Then there is $t>0$ (small enough) so that $v=tw$ has norm smaller than $\delta$. Therefore, $|Df(x_0)(tw)| \leq (C+\epsilon)|tw|$ but then by linearity of $Df(x_0)$ and of the norm: $|t| \|Df(x_0)w\| \leq (C+\epsilon)|t| \|w\|$. Now divide by $|t|$. The assumptions are $f$ differentiable at $x_0$ and $C$-Lipschitz (everywhere or just at $x_0$). The goal was to show that then $\|Df(x_0)\|\leq C$.

Comment: Could you explain why third centered equation follows by continuity?